# Reproject LiDAR from Lat/Long to NAD83 with LAStools not working correctly

Tags: lidar, las, lastools

I'm trying to reproject a NOAA las file from Lat/Long to State Plane NAD83 using las2las.

When I unpack the laz file as an las without specifying input or output coordinates it comes into GIS in the correct place. I know the laz file is in lat/long because I ran las2txt and got point coordinates around -79.9XXXX, 32.8XXXX.

When I try to reproject the file from lat/long it throws it way off in space. It seems like las2las isn't converting the decimal degrees to state plane ft correctly...or rather I am not setting something correctly.

Any ideas?

Here are the NOAA files im using:
https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/lidar3_z/geoid12b/data/8789/

Here is the output from lasinfo:

```
lasinfo (190812) report for 'E:\Lidar\SC\LAS\2017CharlestonBerkeley\20170307_3325-01.laz'
reporting all LAS header entries:
  file signature:             'LASF'
  file source ID:             0
  global_encoding:            17
  project ID GUID data 1-4:   838BCBB1-D3BC-4FD8-0000-000000000000
  version major.minor:        1.4
  system identifier:          'NOAA OCM'
  generating software:        'datum_shift (10070 2019-06-27)'
  file creation day/year:     182/2018
  header size:                375
  offset to point data:       5233
  number var. length records: 2
  point data format:          6
  point data record length:   30
  number of point records:    0
  number of points by return: 0 0 0 0 0
  scale factor x y z:         0.0000001 0.0000001 0.01
  offset x y z:               -79 32 0
  min x y z:                  -79.9584714 32.8044423 -82.88
  max x y z:                  -79.9420337 32.8183239 114.95
  start of waveform data packet record: 0
  start of first extended variable length record: 0
  number of extended_variable length records: 0
  extended number of point records: 15676278
  extended number of points by return: 11226648 2555366 1262869 482928 123994 21530 2678 246 19 0 0 0 0 0 0
variable length header record 1 of 2:
  reserved             0
  user ID              'LASF_Spec'
  record ID            0
  length after header  4096
  description          'Classification Lookup'
    0 Never Classifie    1 Unclassified    2 Ground    3 Low Vegetation    4 Medium Vegetati    5 High Vegetation    6 Building    7 Low Point (nois    8 Model Key Point    9 Water    10 Ignored Ground     11     12     13 Culvert    14     15     16     17 Bridge Deck    18 High Noise    19     20     21     22     23     24     25     26     27     28     29     30     31     32     33     34     35     36     37     38     39     40     41     42     43     44     45     46     47     48     49     50     51     52     53     54     55     56     57     58     59     60     61     62     63     64     65     66     67     68     69     70     71     72     73     74     75     76     77     78     79     80     81     82     83     84     85     86     87     88     89     90     91     92     93     94     95     96     97     98     99     100     101     102     103     104     105     106     107     108     109     110     111     112     113     114     115     116     117     118     119     120     121     122     123     124     125     126     127     128     129     130     131     132     133     134     135     136     137     138     139     140     141     142     143     144     145     146     147     148     149     150     151     152     153     154     155     156     157     158     159     160     161     162     163     164     165     166     167     168     169     170     171     172     173     174     175     176     177     178     179     180     181     182     183     184     185     186     187     188     189     190     191     192     193     194     195     196     197     198     199     200     201     202     203     204     205     206     207     208     209     210     211     212     213     214     215     216     217     218     219     220     221     222     223     224     225     226     227     228     229     230     231     232     233     234     235     236     237     238     239     240     241     242     243     244     245     246     247     248     249     250     251     252     253     254     255 
variable length header record 2 of 2:
  reserved             0
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            2112
  length after header  652
  description          'by LAStools of rapidlasso GmbH'
    WKT OGC COORDINATE SYSTEM:
    COMPD_CS["NAD83(2011); NAVD88 height",GEOGCS["NAD83(2011)",DATUM["NAD83_National_Spatial_Reference_System_2011",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","1116"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6318"]],VERT_CS["NAVD88 height",VERT_DATUM["North American Vertical Datum 1988",2005,EXTENSION["PROJ4_GRIDS","g2012a_conus.gtx,g2012a_alaska.gtx,g2012a_guam.gtx,g2012a_hawaii.gtx,g2012a_puertorico.gtx,g2012a_samoa.gtx"],AUTHORITY["EPSG","5103"]],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192],AXIS["Up",UP],AUTHORITY["EPSG","5703"]]]
the header is followed by 2 user-defined bytes
LASzip compression (version 3.4r1 c3 50000): POINT14 3
reporting minimum and maximum for all LAS point record entries ...
  X            -9584714   -9420337
  Y             8044423    8183239
  Z               -8288      11495
  intensity           0      65534
  return_number       1          7
  number_of_returns   1          7
  edge_of_flight_line 0          0
  scan_direction_flag 0          0
  classification      1         18
  scan_angle_rank   -31         28
  user_data           1          2
  point_source_ID   120        122
  gps_time 172930079.521245 172932250.437906
  extended_return_number          1      9
  extended_number_of_returns      1      9
  extended_classification         1     18
  extended_scan_angle         -5167   4667
  extended_scanner_channel        0      0
number of first returns:        11226648
number of intermediate returns: 1895072
number of last returns:         11225613
number of single returns:       8671055
overview over extended number of returns of given pulse: 8671055 2584009 2339767 1436358 512888 113197 17022 1811 171 0 0 0 0 0 0
histogram of classification of points:
         8114188  unclassified (1)
         4692151  ground (2)
         1539451  building (6)
           52623  noise (7)
          965980  keypoint (8)
            5692  water (9)
             136  rail (10)
             306  wire guard (13)
          305737  bridge deck (17)
              14  Reserved for ASPRS Definition (18)
 +-> flagged as keypoints: 965980
 +-> flagged as withheld:  2236251
 +-> flagged as extended overlap: 1380064
```

Screenshots from las2las setup:

[image: las2las - unknown projection]

[image: las2las - setup]

[image: las2las - coordinate options]

Comment: Could you edit your question to show a screenshot of the projection tool, including your inputs, outputs, options, etc?

Comment: Done! I added the lasinfo output and screenshots of the las2las setup. Let me know if you'd like any other information added. Thanks!

Comment: can you copy and paste the full commands that is generated? (by hitting RUNXY button)
another option is to post your question to the lastools google group: http://groups.google.com/group/lastools/